# C++: Modify same pointer using multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition

I am attempting an experiment with processing images in which I am modifying the color in each pixel. I tried implementing my code using "buckets", in which I divide the image into smaller regions - each receiving a dedicated thread to process the image.

On my end, I do not really care if multiple threads are attempting to modify the same resource, in fact, that seems to be the point. Theoretically, the threads should be modifying different locations in memory in the form of pixels. When printing my results however, only the first tasks seems to iterate - leading me to think that some kind of race condition is occurring.

> The function below is what manages the creation of each task, and
>   supplies it with starting coordinates and span to operate on. I
>   believe this is working fine, but it's here just for context:

```
Image* 
CCManager::CCAsync(uint8_t bucketSize, Image* source, 
                                        const std::vector<float>& correction)
{
    Image* newImg = new Image(); // This will contain our end result
    newImg->resize(source->width(), source->height());

    assert(buckets > 0);

    // Now compute the width and height each bucket will render.
    uint32_t width;
    uint32_t height;

    if(buckets == 2)    // Each bucket takes a vertical rectangle
    {
        width = source->xSize()/2;
        height = source->ySize();
    }
    else
    {
        // Set width and height to produce square grids (powers of 2)
        // *** Not shown for Brevity ***
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> tasks; // The threads we are managing

    // These coordinates will be fed as starting locations for each task
    uint32_t startX = 0;
    uint32_t startY = 0;
    uint8_t  tasksFinished = 0; 

    for(int i = 1; i <= buckets; ++i)
    {   

        // Create a new task with a region for operation
        tasks.emplace_back(std::thread(&CCManager::applyCCTask,this, startX, startY,
                                       width, height, source, newImg, correction));

        // No iteration is required for 1 bucket, simply paint the whole image
        if(buckets == 1){break;}

        // **** I REMOVED PART OF THE CODE THAT SHOWS WHERE EXPONENT
        // IS DEFINED AND DETERMINED FOR BREVITY
        // Reached last column, start a new row
        if(i % exponent == 0)
        {
            startX = 0;
            startY+= height;
        }
        // Keep incrementing horizontally
        else
        {
            startX+= width;
        }
    }

    while(tasksFinished < buckets)
    {
        // Join with whichever tasks finished
        for(int i = 0; i < buckets; ++i)
        {
            if(tasks[i].joinable())
            {
                tasks[i].join();
                tasksFinished++;
            }
        }
    }
    tasks.clear();

    return newImg;
}
```

Having provided the new and source image pointers for each task, here they are in action.

> The follow function retrieves the color in each pixel, and calls a
>   method that applies the correction accordingly.

```
void 
CCManager::applyCCTask(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t width, uint32_t height,
                              Image* source, Image* newImg,
                              const std::vector<float>& correction)
{
    // ** THIS ACTUALLY PRINTS THE CORRECT COORDINATES AND REGION SPAN
    // ** FOR EACH THREAD
    printf("Task renders @ (%i,%i) with %i x %i box\n", x,y,width,height);
    assert(source);
    assert(newImg);

    for (; x < width; ++x )
    {
        for (; y < height; ++y)
        {
            Byte4 pixel = source->pixel (x, y);
            Color color = pixel.color;

            printf("Before correction: Pixel(%i,%i) color [%i,%i,%i]\n",x,y, pixel.color[0], pixel.color[1], pixel.color[2]);
                Color correctedColor= addCorrectionToColor( color, correction);

            Byte4* newPixel= &newImg->pixel( x, y );

            newPixel->color[0] = correctedColor[0];
            newPixel->color[1] = correctedColor[1];
            newPixel->color[2] = correctedColor[2];  

            printf("After correction: Pixel(%i,%i) color [%i,%i,%i]\n",x,y, newImg->pixel( x, y ).color[0], newImg->pixel( x, y ).color[1], newImg->pixel( x, y ).color[2]);
        }
    }

    printf("Task Finished!\n");
}
```

With the code shown, all tasks end up printing the starting message with their area of operation, but inside the nested loop, the "Before" and "After" messages seem to only print from ONE task only.

Why am I not allowed to modify the same image from multiple threads even though the actual pixel data being modified is different for each thread? Can I circumvent that without adding resource locks such as a mutexes, the whole point of this experiment was to allow each thread to run independently without any hindrance.

Comment: `task[i].join()` will not return until `task[i]` has completed.  Your program will never make more than one pass through the `while(tasksFinished < buckets)` loop.

Comment: The "before" and "after" messages do not appear to contain any information.  How are you able to tell which task produced them?

Comment: What does this code actually do to the image when it runs?

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks for the catch on the first point. As for the second point, I am printing the pixel location and associated color as part of the message, and I am able to tell only the pixels managed by one of the tasks is printing. i.e, task#1 operating from (0,0) to (200,0) and task#2 operates from (0,200) to (200,200); Only the iteration from (0,0) to (200,0) is shown.

Comment: @jameslarge I am not saving the image and am unable to display it as part of an app in its current state, so all I am doing is tracking the changes on a per pixel level. I can see the color of the newImg->pixel(x,y) actually being modified by the end of the loop.

Comment: Re, "I am printing the pixel location and associated color as part of the message." The code in your examples doesn't do that. You might want to update your question so that it shows the code that you actually are running.

Comment: Does that program even run right in the single threaded case (buckets==0)?
I wouldn't be sure if those x/y loops are correct, and actually run through each pixel

Comment: @Matthias247 I am embarrassed to say, that was it...I just declared my loop normally and the code executes properly with 1 bucket. Attempting to use 4 buckets ends up working on 1/4th of the image though, but I'll try and verify I am setting up my threads correctly to begin with before following up.

Comment: @Matthias247 Yep, it works fine now